# DIAL protocol for launching android application

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to get an Android TV app to launch with DIAL. I have the application installed on my Android TV as

"com.test.example"

I also have that path registered to the DIAL site, here: http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-registry/namespace-database

I can pair to the Android TV from my phone via DIAL, but any time I try to actually start the application (using the ConnectSDK), I get a very nondescript error message back. There is very little documentation for how this should work. Do I need to register some kind of DIAL receiver in my AndroidManifest for the TV app? How can I get it to recognize what I'm doing. I've tried to pass the "appId" in the following ways...

`appId = "com.text.example"`
`appId = "example"`
`appId = "Example"`

Is there more to this somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434324/using-dial-protocol-in-android-application question

Comment: @RyanInBinary is there any update? Did you manage to resolve it, I´m currently facing the same problem.

Comment: I did not. There was no real help to be found anywhere. I even tried reaching out to the people who maintain the DIAL protocol site, to no avail. If you do any better than I did, please follow up.

Comment: @RyanInBinary Any luck with this? I'm stuck with the same problem. Did you manage to solve it with some other protocol.

Comment: Never solved, only abandoned :(

Answer (score 1):

Your application actually is not registered in the database. Neither in registered names, nor in the registered prefixes.

The reason for that is on the registry's [about page](http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/dial-registry) in the ***Naming rules*** section:

> 3. An Application Prefix MUST be at least four (4) characters in length (after decoding percent-encoded characters) and must include a recognizable company name. For example: “Acme-”, “com.acme”.

You meet the length requirement, but I doubt the part about the recognizable company name.

Comment: It is actually, but I didn't show my actual application name in my question, just an example. It shows up in the registered database.

Comment: I that case, sorry. I took your question too literally.

Comment: I didn't specify, that was my own fault